# filter observations up to less or equal to specific value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data, `df`. The `status` will be filled with a `stop` at the last value of days <=6 and I only keep observations up to `days <=6` or up to `status=Stop` per id. For example, if days are equal to 2,5,7 etc, the cut point will be at 5 as the last logical operator will TRUE at days<=6 is 5.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4),
days=c(1,3,3,4,6,10,11,0,2,3,17,19,20,2,2,4,5,7,9,2,13,15),
status=c('live','live','live','live','live','live','live','live','live','live','live','To','die','live','To','die',
'live','live','live','live','live','To'))
```

i.e.,

```
   id days status
1   1    1   live
2   1    3   live
3   1    3   live
4   1    4   live
5   1    6   live # 6<=6 True, 
6   1   10   live # But 10<=6 False, So status should stop at 5th obs.
7   1   11   live
8   2    0   live
9   2    2   live
10  2    3   live # status should stop at day=3 as 6<=17 is False in the next follow-up.  
11  2   17   live
12  2   19     To
13  2   20    die
14  3    2   live
15  3    2   live
16  3    4   live
17  3    5   live # 5<=6 True 
18  3    7   live # 7<=6 false, so stop should at maximum of True (at day=5)
19  3    9   live
20  4    2   live  # True
21  4   13   live  # false
22  4   15     To
```

Expected output

```
   id days status
1   1    1   live
2   1    3   live
3   1    3   live
4   1    4   live
5   1    6   Stop
6   2    0   live
7   2    2   live
8   2    3   Stop
9   3    2   live
10  3    2     To
11  3    4    die
12  3    5   Stop
13  4    2   Stop
```

I am trying using

```
df %>%  group_by(id) %>%  
  mutate(status = case_when(days >=6  ~ "Stop",  TRUE ~ status)) %>% 
  slice(seq_len(min(which(status=="Stop"), n())))
```

Comment: In the iinput for 2, 3, status is 'live'.  How did it become 'Stop in expected

Comment: Also for id 3, it is only 'live' values in 'status' (in input data)

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun, now I updated for id 3.  sorry